# Requisição Ajax com header Authorization

Tags: jquery, ajax, front-end, http-request, request

Estou tentando fazer uma requisição ajax mas que precisa de uma autenticação do tipo BASIC, segue meu código:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

    $(function(){
      $.post({
        url: link,
        contentType: "application/json",
        data:"1",
        headers: {'Authorization': 'Basic token'},
        success: function(data) {
          console.log(data)
        }, error: function(err) {
          console.log(err)
        }
      });
    });

</script>
```

*coloquei link/token por questões de sigilo, mas estão corretos.
*fiz esta requisição por PHP com mesmo token e parâmetro e funcionou.

Alguém pode me ajudar? Retorna 401 (Unauthorized) / Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 401.

Comment: remove o headers e tente utilizar 
beforeSend: function (xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader ("Authorization", "Basic otken");
},

mas acredito que o problema nao esta no seu envio, voce consegue depurar a url que voce esta chamando?

Comment: eu tentei com beforeSend, continuou o mesmo erro =/ e não consigo depurar por ser uma url privada

Comment: no DevTools do chrome (F12), na aba de NETWORK na requisição esta indo correto sua requisição na parte do headers? Pode ser tosco, mas tente trocar de Authorization para authorization.

Comment: troquei por authorization e continuou o mesmo erro =/ lá no headers aparece Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization,content-type , acredito que o Authorization esteja indo. Mas por alguma razão não tá autenticando. Ele identifica também o WWW-Authenticate: Basic , o problema deve ser no recebimento do token, não sei

Comment: ou então tira o header daí e criar um outro em cima do post chamado `$.ajaxSetup({ headers: { 'Autorizaition': 'Basic token' } })`

Comment: já tinha tentado anteriormente e tentei agora novamente, mesmo erro =/

Comment: entao pode ser o servico que voce esta acessando, o token esta correto?

Comment: está sim, via PHP eu consegui a requisição sem bronca (com o mesmo token)